# Different styling on background in html <option>

Tags: css, html-select

I would like to style some `<option>` elements inside a `<select>` element in some unique ways, dynamically. This goes beyond the simple working examples of the "background-color" CSS; I'm trying to find ways where I don't have to keep resources but could generate styles dynamically such as adding some gradient or image from data-uri to the background.
Well, so far, no gradients are working and neither does data-uri  with `background` or `background-image`.
Besides perhaps backgrounds, what other ways can option elements be styled to make it looks like there's extra stuff in there but that doesn't rely on a static resource?

Comment: Is using `<canvas>` an option?

Comment: Not possible with only HTML and CSS.

Comment: [Styling `<select>` is hard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Styling_with_CSS), styling `<option>` is harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you cannot style a select element or an option element. The select element itself is a "replaced element" which is OS-dependent and not part of the HTML/browser. It cannot be styled via CSS.

However you can use replacement plug-ins/libraries that look like a select element but are actually composed of regular HTML elements in which the style can be changed.